# ASP.Net Can't Login/Register successfully ( works locally but not on Azure )

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, asp.net-identity

**Edit2 : What i found is that it logins correctly and give the cookie of the user ( .AspNet.ApplicationCookie ) but when it is there ( when running on the deployed version of the WebApp, not locally) nothing will load, so the eternal load is simply a redirect to the home page, i don't know what it could be..**

At first i tought it was the Database connection that was wrong or something... but i just realised by login in the admin panel locally that the accounts i was trying to register using the deployed Web App were registering in the DB successfully, even though after doing the registration you are stuck in an eternal loading screen..

I don't know what could be wrong since it is 100% functional locally , but somehow it seems like you can't sign in/login when it is deployed in Azure.

**Edit :** Somehow this morning i've tried logging in and it gave me a Runtime Error :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>        Runtime Error
>        Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated

Now i've been asked the more info :

> When you test locally, make certain that the application is not
>   creating any .mdf files in within your project's App_Data folder on
>   the filesystem. If it is, this is a sure indication as to why it works
>   locally but not when deployed to azure. Technically, you can have
>   separate connection strings and thus separate databases for your
>   application and your application services.

When i test locally, no file is made in the App_Data folder as it uses the same database while deploying as when running it locally -> can register new accounts locally and on the deploy

Now for this :

> Please update your question with your web.config file. Be sure to
>
> include the membership and roleManager sections under
>
> . The exception message indicates that the connection
>   string name you are using for application services (meaning
>   membership, role management, etc) is referencing a database that lives
>   in your App_Data directory. Be sure to omit any usernames and
>   passwords from your  when you post the web.config.

In my Web.config i do not have any roleManager section nor membership(i don't use membership but i do use roleManager?)

as per requested here is some important code with the registration :

This is what happens when someone register ( AccountController )

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                user.Subscribed = false;
                user.StartSubscription = new DateTime?();
                user.EndSubscription = null;
                user.paypalProfileID = null;

                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

and this is the ApplicationUser identity :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public string paypalProfileID { get; set; }
        public bool? Subscribed { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartSubscription { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndSubscription { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code, and maybe some logs.

Comment: @JackZeng the code for registering/Loging in is the basic code from an asp.net Web App Project ( auto generated registeration/login )

Answer (score 0):

&#$&$#@&@#$U@#$*$@#*$#@*#@$*#@$*(!$(@()@#($!@(@$(@$

It was the NAV the whole time :

```
 @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "AdminPage", "Admin")</li>
                    }
```

doesn't seem to work deployed without having

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

in the Web.Config

...